# How to display line chart like a "steps"

Tags: google-visualization

For example the just below is the standard line chart
[image]

Though I want to see on the reports the chart like this:
[image]

Though I want to see on the reports the chart like this, so the series looks like a steps.

Is it possible to do it with google charts? I spent whole day to figure out if it is possible or not, though I didn't find any good solution.

Comment: Any idea to get it worked?

Comment: This is the best place to get some idea.... https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#stepped_area_chart

Comment: yes, I know this place though can't find how to do DOT logbook chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google charts currently doesn't support strings on the Y-Axis. We're looking at adding this feature in a later release of the charting API, so please stay tuned.